# $S$ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$S = \{ [a, b]  \in \mathbb{R}^2 | ab \ge 0\}$$

My attempt at a solution:

Case 1) $0$ vector exists as $0 \times 0 \ge 0$

Case 2) $u = [a,b], v = [c,d],$

$u+v = [a+c, b+d]$

Because $ab \ge 0$, 
we are only looking at value $\ge 0$, meaning $a+c \ge 0$ and $b+d \ge 0$

Case 3) $u = [1,2], -u =[-1,-2]$, $(-1) \times(-2) \ge 0$

True

Comment: The only non-trivial subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$ are lines through the origin. $S$ consists of vectors whose coordinates have the same sign, i.e., the entire first and third quadrants of the plane, therefore it can’t be a subspace. So, you should look for violations of the vector space axioms. Closure under addition is the likely candidate since scalar multiplication affects both signs in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that your "proof" is not for arbitrary elements - specifically **Case 3** needs to be a universal proof...a single example does not prove closure under scalar multiplication to hold for all elements (at least it won't convince anybody)

The second problem is that your proof is not a proof. Take $\vec{u} = (1, 5), \  \vec{v} = (-5, -1)$, both are in $S$, but the $\vec{u} + \vec{v}$ is not.

Comment: You're right, for whatever reason I thought the condition on ab >= 0 would force the matrix to be all numbers >= 0

Comment: Actually $(1,1) + (-5,-5) = (-4,-4)$ is in $S$.  I guess you wanted to take $u = (1,5)$ and $v = (-5,-1)$...

Comment: Sorry! I messed up my counterexample. The main point is to make one of them negative and one of them positive using a completely negative vector. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

$$[1,0] \in S$$
$$[0,-1] \in S$$

but $$[1+0,0-1]=[1,-1] \notin S.$$

Hence, $S$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Remark for your proof of closure for scalar multiplication, we have to prove it for general elements rather than a specific element.